# Put an image into a header and make it take up the full page

Tags: google-docs

In MS Word, I think you can put an image into a header and make it take up the full page... this is a workaround to give a page a background image.

If I try this in Google docs, the image gets cut off around halfway down the page.

Is this do-able in Google Docs?

Answer (score 1):

#### Background Images in Docs

In Google Docs background images are referred to as **Watermarks**.

To add one navigate to **Insert** menu ▶  **Watermark**

Then customize as needed.